# How to link from one Google Document to another

Tags: google-drive, links

In Google Drive I have two documents, let's call them A and B. How do I make some sort of link inside document A so that it can be clicked on and the user is taken to document B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the top right of the document is a blue button that says Share (with a lock over it) -- click this, the "link to share" field will already be highlighted with the URL to your document. Copy and Paste that URL in the other document. Click on it. That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

Press `Ctrl` `K` in document **A** at the desired position and instead of typing or pasting in a URL into the dialog box that appears, run a search for document **B**, select it and click `Apply`. (Source: [Link Between Documents in Google Drive](https://gizmodo.com/link-between-documents-in-google-drive-1647059015)).